# Is there a way I can load accented letters to hive using openCSVSerde?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue, hive-serde, lazysimpleserde

I am trying to load a table in Hive which has accented letters. I was initially using openCSVSerde to parse the CSV file and load it to the table. However, when I come to the accented letters, it prints a � in place of the accented letters. I have tried several methods but it is not working.

1. Using openCSVserde, I tried declaring `serialization.encoding = 'windows-1252'` inside the `TBLPROPERTIES` section, it did not resolve the issue. I did check again by adding `serialization.encoding = 'windows-1252'` inside `WITH SERDEPROPERTIES`. That also did not work.
2. Using openCSVserde, I tried explicitly declaring `serialization.encoding = 'utf-8'` inside the `WITH SERDEPROPERTIES`, it did not work.
3. Using openCSVserde, I tried declaring `serialization.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'` inside the `WITH SERDEPROPERTIES`, it did not work.

I, then, switched over to LazySimpleSerde as I read somewhere, that it is compatible with accented characters. I tried setting `serialization.encoding = 'windows-1252'` inside `WITH SERDEPROPERTIES` which worked, but it brought a new error. Some of the text columns had quotes which split the data and loaded it incorrectly into the table.

1. So now, I tried using `'quote.delim'='"'` inside `WITH SERDEPROPERTIES` which did not fix the incorrect data-split.
2. I tried using `'quoteChar'='"'` inside `WITH SERDEPROPERTIES` which ,also, did not fix the incorrect data-split.

I reverted to openCSVSerde and tried using `serialization.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'` inside `WITH SERDEPROPERTIES` as well as
`store.charset = 'ISO-8859-1',retrieve.charset = 'ISO-8859-1'`
inside `TBLPROPERTIES`, which solved the incorrect data-split but brought me back to not being able to print the accented characters. I also tried `serialization.encoding = 'utf-16'` inside `WITH SERDEPROPERTIES`, which, unsurprisingly, did not resolve the issue.

Can anyone tell how I can use openCSVSerde to print the accented letters?